# HTML5 Video Stop onClose

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I'm using jQuery tools for an overlay. Inside the overlay I have an HTML5 video. However, when I close the overlay, the video keeps playing. Any idea how I might get the video to stop when I close the overlay? Here's the code I have:

```
$("img[rel]").overlay({ onClose: function() { <stop the video somehow> }, mask: { color: '#000', opacity: 0.7 }});
```

I tried using

```
$('video').pause();
```

But this paused the overlay as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem may be with jquery selector you've chosen
`$("video")` is not a selector

The right selector may be putting an **id** element for **video** tag i.e.
Let's say your video element looks like this:

```
<video id="vid1" width="480" height="267" oster="example.jpg" durationHint="33"> 
    <source src="video1.ogv" /> 
    <source src="video2.ogv" /> 
</video>
```

Then you can select it via `$("#vid1")` with **hash mark** (#), id selector in jquery.
If a video element is exposed in function,then you have access to **HtmlVideoElement** (HtmlMediaElement).This elements has control over video element,in your case you can use `pause()` method for your video element.

Check reference for VideoElement [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#video).
Also check that there is a fallback reference [here](http://www.html5video.org/demos/).

Comment: Using an ID is rather annoying if you can have N videos.

Comment: What if I want to stop _all_ videos from playing? (e.g. wildcard)

Comment: ```$("video")``` *is* a selector, but you have to use ```$("video")[0]``` to get the first match, like: ```$("video")[0].pause()```

Answer (score 27):

If you want to stop every movie tag in your page from playing, this little snippet of jQuery will help you:

```
$("video").each(function () { this.pause() });
```

Answer (score 13):

**Starting Video with different browsers**

For Opera 12

```
window.navigator.getUserMedia(param, function(stream) {
                            video.src =window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                        }, videoError );
```

For Firefox Nightly 18.0

```
window.navigator.mozGetUserMedia(param, function(stream) {
                            video.mozSrcObject = stream;
                        }, videoError );
```

For Chrome 22

```
window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(param, function(stream) {
                            video.src =window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                        },  videoError );
```

**Stopping video with different browsers**

For Opera 12

```
video.pause();
video.src=null;
```

For Firefox Nightly 18.0

```
video.pause();
video.mozSrcObject=null;
```

For Chrome 22

```
video.pause();
video.src="";
```

Comment: This seems to not really be directed specifically at the question asked

Answer (score 11):

The following works for me:

```
$('video')[0].pause();
```

Answer (score 9):

Someone already has the answer.

$('video') will return an array of video items. It is totally a valid seletor!

so

```
$("video").each(function () { this.pause() });
```

will work.

Answer (score 3):

For a JQM+PhoneGap app the following worked for me.

The following was the minimum I had to go to get this to work.  I was actually experiencing a stall due to the buffering while spawning ajax requests when the user pressed the back button.  Pausing the video in Chrome and the Android browser kept it buffering.  The non-async ajax request would get stuck waiting for the buffering to finish, which it never would.

Binding this to the beforepagehide event fixed it.

```
 $("#SOME_JQM_PAGE").live("pagebeforehide", function(event)
 {
           $("video").each(function () 
           { 
               logger.debug("PAUSE VIDEO");
               this.pause();
               this.src = "";
           });
 });
```

This will clear every video tag on the page.

The important part is this.src = "";

Comment: I used $('video').each(function(k,v){ jQuery('video')[k].pause(); }); which works for me, got the idea from this thread and @jantoine thread. Haven't test with IE.

Answer (score 2):

My experience with Firefox is that adding the '`id`' attribute to a video element causes Firefox to crash completely...as in asking you to submit a bug report. Remove the `id` element and it works fine. I am not sure if this is true for everyone, but I thought I'd share my experience in case it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To save hours of coding time, use a jquery plug-in already optimized for embedded video iframes.

I spent a couple days trying to integrate Vimeo's moogaloop API with jquery tools unsuccessfully. See [this list](http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/01/10-promising-jquery-lighbox-plugin/) for a handful of easier options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($.browser.msie)
{
   // Some other solution as applies to whatever IE compatible video player used.
}
else
{
   $('video')[0].pause();
}
```

But, consider that $.browser is deprecated, but I haven't found a comparable solution.

Comment: Since `$.broswer` is deprecated, maybe this isn't a good solution - particularly since there's already an accepted answer?