# Youtube video still playing when overlay is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, overlay

I have an overlay with an embedded youtube video that opens up when the page is loaded, which all works wonderfully considering this is the first time I've done anything like this. However, whenever the overlay is closed while the video is playing, the video can be heard playing in the background and I do not know how to solve this.
I am at a complete loss, and due to my inexperience when it comes to coding, I don't know what to do with the solutions I have found via google. If anyone could help me, I would appreciate it greatly!

Below is the code for the overlay, feel free to comment on any improvements I could make to it as well as possible solutions to my problem.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Overlay</title>
  <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>  
   <style>
    #box {
    display:none;
    width:880px;
    border:10px solid #666;
    border:10px solid rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.698);
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
  }
  #box div {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #3B5998;
    background-color:#fff;
    font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif
  }
  #box h2 {
    margin:-11px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#6D84B4;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #3B5998;
    font-size:20px;
  }
  </style>
$(‘#videofeed’).appendTo(‘body’);
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
  .box {
  background:transparent;
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#333333,endColorstr=#333333    );
  zoom: 1;
  }
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- dialog -->
<div id="box">
  <div>
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
    <table width="620" border="0" cellpadding ="0" cellspacing = "0" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
  <tr>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="480"><iframe width="854" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ej08Oju4tu8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></td>
  </tr>
  </table>      
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#open_now").click(function() {
      $("#box").overlay().load();
  });
  $("#box").overlay({
    top: 260,   
    mask: {
    color: '#fff',
    loadSpeed: 200,
    opacity: 0.5
    },
    closeOnClick: true,
    load: true
    });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this a typo: </style>
$(‘#videofeed’).appendTo(‘body’);  ?

Comment: Perhaps this will help you;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879227/html5-video-stop-onclose

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#box').remove();
```

after closing the overlay

or just `$('#box iframe').remove();`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Where abouts in the code would I be putting this? I've been trying to work on this all day, so my brain is a little fried...

Comment: just add `onClose: function() {
  /* the code */
  }` to your `overlay()`

Comment: Note: That $().remove() deletes the element from the DOM. If you wish to show the video later, you will need to re-add it to the DOM. If this is okay, then that will work just fine.

Comment: Sorry for the very delayed response, I lost internet access. Joys of living in the country. Everytime I add     onClose: function() it prevents the overlay loading programatically. Is there any reason for this? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you sure you added it inside the overlay-function? If you use Firefox, try Strg+Shift+K to display the console. Are there any errors shown?