# Video pop up modal playing in background when closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I am using the Magnific Popup and it works fine in Chrome but across Mozilla and IE when I close the pop up modal the audio will still play in the background.

I have searched online for others having issues with this but I cannot locate a solution that works. The video is just a html video, no YouTube or anything. Here is the code I am using.

```
function displayVideoAsPopup(selector,attr) {
    $(selector).each(function(i,e) {
        var videoSrc=$(e).attr(attr);
        if($(e)[0].localName=="a"){
            $(e).attr("href","javascript:void(0)"); 
        }
        $(e).magnificPopup({
            items: {
                type: 'inline',
                src: '<div class="container"><video controls preload="auto" autoplay width="100%" height="100%" src="' + videoSrc + '"></video></div>',
            },
            callbacks: {
                open: function() {
                    $(this.content).find('video')[0].play();

                },
                close: function() {
                    $(this.content).find('video')[0].load();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please add a running snippet which shows your problem. I see you have put the callback event for the close. There you should stop the video from playing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're calling load() on the video instead of pause() on popup close, is it normal?

```
function displayVideoAsPopup(selector, attr) {
    $(selector).each(function (i, e) {
        var videoSrc = $(e).attr(attr);
        if ($(e)[0].localName == "a") {
            $(e).attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
        }
        $(e).magnificPopup({
            items: {
                type: 'inline',
                src: '<div class="container"><video controls preload="auto" autoplay width="100%" height="100%" src="' + videoSrc + '"></video></div>',
            },
            callbacks: {
                open: function () {
                    $(this.content).find('video')[0].play();

                },
                close: function () {
                    // Call pause() here instead of load()
                    $(this.content).find('video')[0].pause();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

You should set the src of the video element to "" or null too after pausing. 
[HTML5 Video Stop onClose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879227/html5-video-stop-onclose)

Answer (score 0):

First pause the video then load it will work
`$("video").each(function() {
this.pause();
this.load();
});`

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old. But for anyone who comes here searching for the answer, you do not need `callbacks` to do this. The video already has `autoplay` attribute which will start playing the video once the popup opens. The video will stop playing when it closes. So the `magnificPopup` should just look like below:

```
$(e).magnificPopup({
    items: {
        type: 'inline',
        src: '<div class="container"><video controls preload="auto" autoplay width="100%" height="100%" src="' + videoSrc + '"></video></div>',
    }
});
```